# Character who repeatedly fails even after trying?

Tags: scripture, philosophy

1. Is there any character in epics/scriptures (Mahabharata, Ramayana, etc.) who does not gain a skill they have worked on for long? What is their thought process after this; what do they do?

For example, major characters in Mahabharata are 'experts' in their fields.

2. What do the scriptures suggest for this?

[BG 2.47](https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/2/verse/47). Sri Krishna says

> You have a right to perform your prescribed duties, but you are not entitled to the fruits of your actions. Never consider yourself to be the cause of the results of your activities, nor be attached to inaction.

Does this imply - The person continue working on that? Or they "change their field"?

Comment: Regarding the downvote, it would be great if you tell me how to improve the question